# CSS - @media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

```
/* 1024 and above desktop ------ */
@media only screen
and (min-width: 1008px){
    /* Styles */
    .outerBox{
        width: 796px;
    }

@media only screen
and (min-width: 600px)
and (max-width: 640px){
    /* Styles */
    .outerBox{
        width: 600px;
    }
}
```

The queries above doesn't seem to work properly when applied together..as only the first one works when both applied and if I remove the first one the second one works fine..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first rule is missing the closing `}`:

```
/* 1024 and above desktop ------ */
@media only screen
and (min-width: 1008px){
    /* Styles */
    .outerBox{
        width: 796px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds ;) 1+